# C# - Creating an array of strings within a For Loop

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following code where I am attemping to take the GeneralAgency property off of each employer and add it to a new array of strings called agencies. However, I am getting the error "Use of unassigned local variable 'agencies'" Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
            var employers = _employerRepository.GetByTaxId(taxId).ToList(); //gives me list of employer objects
            string[] agencies;
            for (int i = 0; i < employers.Count(); i++ )
            {
                agencies[i] = employers[i].GeneralAgency;
            }
```

Comment: agencies is never assigned.  It is null, so indexing into it should fail.

Comment: You need to initialize the variable, like so: `string[] agencies = new string[employers.Count];` As a further note, `_employerRepository.GetByTaxId(taxId).Select(a => a.GeneralAgency).ToArray()` would also give you what you want without the extra loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the following :

```
var employers = _employerRepository.GetByTaxId(taxId).ToList();    
string[] agencies = new string[employers.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < employers.Count; i++ )
{
    agencies[i] = employers[i].GeneralAgency;
}
```

And also if you don't need this loop you can do just :

```
var agencies = _employerRepository.GetByTaxId(taxId).Select(a => a.GeneralAgency).ToArray();
```

It's just simple LINQ code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the array first. You also need to specify the size of the array.

```
agencies = new string[employers.Count()];
```

Arrays in C# always have a fixed length. If you don't know the size beforehand, use a List<>.

You could also use LINQ to write the code shorter:

```
var agencies = from employer in employers select employer.GeneralAgency;
```